# how to enable ssl in auto assigned ip of aws ec2 running apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, express, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an amazon ec2 instance running apache server and nodejs express app. It has an auto assigned IP - **http://ec2-13-126-38-24.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com**

I want to be able to access my node app on "https" instead of just http as it needs to be integrated with a frontend app. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Its kind of stupid that heroku provides ssl enabled subdomains by default but aws does not. What am I missing here?

Comment: It is good practice to get a static IP for your server, you never know when you have to restart that machine. Make sure you have the domain certificates and properly installed the certificates in apache and have apache redirect to routes in the nodejs app.

Comment: the routes itself of node app works fine - I just want to avoid getting a domain name as I am just developing things out. The frontend is hosted on heroku which is SSL enabled - so it does not allow me to make calls to aws api due to insecure http.

Comment: checkout this blog post https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is intentional. AWS does not allow adding SSL certificates to their auto assigned domain. It wont work even if you try lets encrypt. Only solution is to have a custom domain instead.